# Storing values of a loop in matrix using R

Tags: r, loops

A have the following matrices

```
w= 
    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.4
    0.1  0.0  0.5  0.2  0.0
    0.0  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.0
    0.0  0.0  0.6  0.0  0.0
    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
c=
    0.1  0.0  0.00   0.0   0.00
    0.0  0.4  0.00   0.0   0.00
    0.0  0.0  0.25   0.0   0.00
    0.0  0.0  0.00   0.2   0.00
    0.0  0.0  0.00   0.0   0.05

x = seq(1, 1, length=5)
result = matrix()
```

I built a loop in R.:

```
nloop=10
for (i in 1:nloop)
{
    u=x %*% t(w) 

    x=(x %*% t(w))+((u) %*% t(c))

    x=1/(1+exp(x))

    result=matrix(nrow=10 , ncol = 5)
    for (i in 1:10)
    {
        result[[i]] =x 
    }
}
```

R returns this error:

> Error in result[[i]] = x :    more elements supplied than there are
>   to replace

I want to store the values of each loop in `result` matrix

Comment: Please `dput` w and c so we don't have to replicate your data structures.  Also, why don't you say what you'd like to achieve.  I'm betting there's a way to do it without loops (which are not your problem here; the matrix dimensions are).

Comment: wrong index for `result`; should not define result inside the loop;

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, what’s the problem with my matrix dimensions?

Comment: @liuminzhao, outside the loop the results matrix is empty, hence no results

Comment: You are overwriting 'result' in every pass through the loop and you are addressing a matrix with "[[". Please delete or edit. At the moment this is just user-error with no clear goal statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It is not elegant but it works.

```
result = vector("list") 

nloop=10
    for (i in 1:nloop)
    { 
    u=x %*% t(w) 
    x=(x %*% t(w))+((u) %*% t(c))
    x=1/(1+exp(1*x))
    result[[i]]=(x)
    }


 result=do.call(rbind, result)
```

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

matrix<-matrix(ncol=numberOfCols,nrow=numberOfRows);

matrix[rowNum,]<-row; # rowNum is the number of row that you're overwriting.